# How can I use id and value of text input?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Textbox:

```
<input class="qty_txt" input id="1234" type="text"  placeholder="Current item QTY">
```

Javascript:

```
$(".qty_txt").on("change", function () {

var productID = elem.id;
var qty = elem.value;

alert(productID + qty);

});
```

How can I use the ID from the textbox, define it as 'productID' and define the value of the texbox as 'qty' to use in the rest of the function?

http://jsfiddle.net/VnYm7/4/

Answer (score 1):

One of the easier things to do would be to pass in the current division as a parameter to the function using the jQuery `$(this)` selector. This way, the same function works for all the .qty-txt classes.

You can use the `.attr()` method of jQuery to get the ID of the div, and then call `.val()` to get the value. You could also use native JS' `.value` method here.

Important to note: the `$(document).ready()` wrapper around the jQuery code assures that that code will be called right when the page loads. If it weren't called, the browser wouldn't know to do things if the input box is changed.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!--jQuery Google CDN-->
        <script type="text/javascript">
               $(document).ready(function() { 
                   $(".qty_txt").on("change", function ($(this)) {

                       var productID = $(this).attr("id");
                       var qty = $(this).val();

                       alert(productID + qty);

                   });
               });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="qty_txt" input id="1234" type="text"  placeholder="Current item QTY">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i did not down vote however script tags should be in body or head preferably head if so you require head tags. script tags should always have a type in this incase `<script type="text/javascript">`. you have done a full html layout where is the include of jquery? also you are supposed to explain an answer not just give code, if this were highly complex no one would know what you might have done!

Comment: @MartinBarker Thanks for the tips :) I'm relatively new to SO, still trying to get the hang of things. You are right in what you said, however, JavaScript is the default type for script tags in HTML5, so specifying it isn't necessary.

Comment: yeah it's still nice to use it, just incase someone comes in on IE 9 or worse :) we're as an added tag to an element wont break anything so it helps with backward support

Comment: good point, I always forget that some people might still be using older browsers like that. Thanks for the tips! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var productID = $(this).attr('id');
var qty = $(this).val();
```

[This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjJoX9F_F5g) video better illustrates the use of `this` and contexts in javascript

Comment: `this` does what `this` has always done it's a pointer to the class in the case of javascript the function containing what your running, i think you mean jQuery as that run's all code local to the HTML Object of the selected items. E.G `HTMLLIElement.jQueryEvtHanderClick();` so then when it call that `this` is the `HTMLLiElement`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve attributes from the event's target, you can use specify a parameter in the `function ()` you pass to `on()`, like this:

```
$(".qty_txt").on("change", function (e) {
  var productID = e.target.id;
  var qty = e.target.value;

  alert(productID + ":" +  qty);
});
```

Take a look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) for details.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" class="qty_txt" id="id1" />
        <input type="text" class="qty_txt" id="id2" />
        <input type="text" class="qty_txt" id="id3" />
        <script>
        $(".qty_txt").on("change", function () {
          var productID = this.id, qty = this.value;
          alert(productID + qty);
        });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is example with several input with different ids, you may bind the "change" function to all the ".qty_txt" elements! the productID and productValue you may get by the code above!

Comment: Please add some explanation in addition to the code